# How to fill a textbox with a "canned response"?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

(Disclaimer/confession of my sins: I got stuck in Windows/Desktop apps for a long time, so my web skills are woefully underdeveloped.  So please pardon my dumb newbie questions in matters of UI!)

I am writing an ASP/MVC3-Razor UI.  My model contains the following properties (among others):

```
public string MyResponse { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<CannedResponse> CannedResponses { get; set; }
```

where `CannedResponse` has the properties

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
```

On the UI I have a text area for the user to enter his response text.  Or, to save time, he could select a canned response from a drop-down, and that should populate the text area with the canned response text.

I'm OK with getting all the right data into the model.  The part I don't know how to do is creating the drop-down list with a client side event to fill the "MyResponse" text area with the "Text" property of the selected canned response.  I assume this has to be done in Javascript, but I'm not sure how to tie the Razor code to the Javascript.  What I have so far is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cboCanned", Model.CannedResponsed.Select(c => 
  new SelectListItem { Value = c.ID.ToString(), Text = c.Description } ))
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MyResponse)
```

What should the JavaScript code be, and how do I hook it up to the drop down selection event?

Comment: You could do this on the server if that's easier: have a menu of canned responses and a submit button, which submits a GET to the server, which in turn serves the page again but with the response pre-filled in the text area. However that will, of course, refresh the form back to its original state, so not ideal if the user is in the process of editing other controls.

Comment: @halfer, yeah, but that's less efficient, and I want to do this on the client side, even if just for the sake of learning!

Comment: You can certainly do this with JS, but I think readers would prefer you to give it a go first `:)`. Is jQuery a possibility for you? If so, it's really easy - just load the library, get a DOM ready listener, and then in that set up a menu change event, and in that, reset the value of the textarea. Sounds complicated, but if you split it into pieces and web-search for each bit, you'll be fine. The jQuery docs are excellent.

Comment: @halfer - {grins uncomprehendlingly}... ehhh... could you please point me at some starting step?  How to load the library, get a DOM ready listenere? etc.?  (I really am very new at this Web UI stuff!)

Comment: Loading the library: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>`. DOM ready is just the event the browser triggers when it is ready to address the structure of the HTML, see here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Comment: Capturing a change event on a control: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: A great way to learn jQuery is to do it step by step, and pop an alert box in the bit you've done. So your first step is to write some JS on your page to pop up a message on DOM ready. How to do it is, verbatim, on the ready link above ^. Then do the same with the change event, link above again ^.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood that MyResponse is the variable holding the "value" of your selection, so this should help:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyResponse , 
                              new SelectList{ Value = c.ID.ToString(), Text = c.Description },          
                              "Value", "Text", Model.MyResponse ))
```

1st parameter:
Which value to bind the DropDownList with:
`m => m.MyResponse` (This is your model, which you're sending to the Razor view)

2nd parameter:
Your list *(Notice that you could pass the list in the model, in order not to create it in the view just to keep the view as simple as possible)*

3rd parameter:
`"Value"` (The name of the property holding the value member of the list's elements)

4th parameter:
`"Text"` (The name of the property holding the display member of the list's elements)

5th parameter:
`Model.MyResponse` (The selected variable in the model holding the selected item's **value**)

Hope this info was useful...